# install a private gem systemwide by using chef-rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, rbenv

I'm using `[chef-rbenv][1]` and install gems systemwide like this:

#### node/my_server.json

```
  "rbenv": {
        "rubies": ["2.2.0"],
        "global": "2.2.0",
        "root_path": "/opt/rbenv",
        "gems": {
            "2.2.0": [
                { "name": "activesupport"},
                { "name": "awesome_print"}
            ]
        }
   }
```

I want to install my private gem `my_foo` like this. 
The gem works fine in local environments, by writing Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'my_foo', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:ironsand/my_foo.git'
gem 'pry-byebug'
```

The server root account have access right to the git repository.

I found information that if I install own gem server I can install the gem, but I prefer not to install the gem server.

Is there a way to install private gem by using `chef-rbenv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's `gem` can't install gems from a git location. This is a feature of bundler. The chef cookbook you're using, implements a wrapper of rubygems' `gem` command, not bundler.

You need to clone the private repo to a directory and build/install the gem yourslef OR pre-build a `.gem` file (see [github's release hosting feature](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) for a nice file hosting functionality that sticks to your private github access management).

Or just call bundler on the Gemfile you're mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation! I'll stick with bundler way.